# How to solve this issue when I try to upload my war file in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

This is the fail message when I try to deploy my web app using tomcat 8.5 version in Apache tomcat

Message:
FAIL - War file [pafSAmple.war] cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear. What have you tried, after reading it, so far?

Comment: I have developed a dynamic web application in Eclipse then I tried to deploy my project's war file in Apache tomcat local host. while I was trying, I got this error message in Apache tomcat localhost  (FAIL - War file [pafSAmple.war] cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml) .I am really sorry unable to upload the image of error msg

Comment: There's no use in uploading images of error messages (don't upload pictures of textual content). This error message talks about server.xml: Have you looked at that file? And what's defined in there? Hint: Look for something related to the name of your application

Comment: Yes. my application name is  mentioned within the host tag of my server.xml file

Comment: ...and it _"cannot be uploaded if context is defined in server.xml"_. Problem solved?

Comment: Yes. thankyou so much it solved. But  I have an another issue after the deployment of war file When I type in the url to my application I get a 404 error could you please help to solve this???

Comment: Can't - not in a comment to this question. As the solution to _this_ question is trivial, I'd consider to close/delete it. If you have another question, ask a new one. But remember to provide a [mcve], and expected as well as observed results.